# What is the most efficient (fastest) way of passing data from C++ to Java?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

What is the most efficient way of passing data from C++ to Java?

The Java application will need to call the C++ application to retrieve the data.

I can see the following ways of achieving this:

1. Using JNI
2. Using a file based approach
3. Using SWIG

My current thinking is to use JNI. Am I missing a better method before I commit?

Comment: Define _efficiency_ please. For speed, or easy to use and maintain code.

Comment: Efficiency only applies to speed right?  I would have asked for the simplest method otherwise :)

Comment: _"Efficiency only applies to speed right?"_ No. That totally depends on your actual requirements priority.

Comment: Those *two* ways are the *three* most common ways of doing that...

Comment: Maybe I don't fully grasp the meaning of SWIG, but isn't kind of the same thing as what the _JNI Invocation API_ is?  (The invocation API allows you to embed a JVM in a C or C++ program.  It's somewhat more complicated than using JNI merely to invoke native methods from within a Java program.)

Comment: How about running the Java code and the C++ code as separate micro-services that communicate with each other via some kind of network API?

Answer (score 1):

JNI would be the best approach. Notice that javah creates compatible header-files for your java-class, its very tricky to to write compatible header-files by your own, so please use javah.

Answer (score 1):

Java Native Interface allows you to pass anything back and forth between C++ and Java. It supports both directions, but can be tricky. There are others you can look at Swig is one and then you have JNA. I would go with JNI