# What is the most efficient way to pass in memory data structure (tabular like) from C++ to Java?

Tags: java, c++, apache-arrow

Is it still the best answer in terms not coping data in memory?
([What is the most efficient(fastest) way of passing data from C++ to Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37172092/what-is-the-most-efficientfastest-way-of-passing-data-from-c-to-java))

I was thinking about Apache Arrow and I see two options:

1. Building Apache Arrow data structure in C++, "serialising" it to bytes, passing bytes via JNI to Java class (AFAIK requires coping of data between C++ process memory and JVM heap).
2. Using Apache Arrow Plasma, but it requires running Plasma server AFAIU.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Efficient in what way? Coding time? Maintenance? memory use? Performance?

Comment: Memory use, I want to create data structure in C and pass it to Java, without coping it to another jvm-like object.

Comment: If you're not using a man-in-the-middle like the Arrow Plasma, how are you planning to forward the data from one executable to another? If they're on the same system I guess you could use staging folders passing around JSON files, that might be the easiest mechanism.  If the java is running a web interface, that would make it even easier.  Just have the C applications throw it at the Java endpoint in a known format (again, I'd use JSON, but XML would work).

Comment: Simply using the C++ API of Apache Arrow from Java with something like the JavaCPP Presets for Arrow is probably most efficient: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/tree/master/arrow

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using Apache Arrow Flight? You could set up server in C++ and client on the Java side? https://github.com/apache/arrow/tree/master/java/flight/flight-core/src/main/java/org/apache/arrow/flight/example

Note that this is still experimental and the API might change so it's not yet production ready.

Answer (score 2):

Flight (as mentioned by @TDrabas) is a great choice and will likely give great performance with minimal work.

Another choice is to write the data in Arrow IPC format to a memory mapped file in C++ and then read it back in Java.  It may be faster as you can avoid a memory copy.

There is [work in progress](https://github.com/apache/arrow/pull/11067) on support for the [C data interface](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/format/CDataInterface.html) which may be something to consider in the future.

Comment: By writing to memory mapped file you mean using MappedByteBuffer?

Comment: Yes, this will probably involve a copy of your data as well.  Typically you will be creating your data in C, then writing it out using an IPC writer to a memory mapped file (this is a copy and it will also be tricky to know exactly how large to make the file ahead of time).  Then you transmit the name of the file and the size to Java via JNI or whatever mechanism.  Then you create a MappedByteBuffer using that information.  Then you read that using an IPC reader.